# Can I create a GAE app that runs an uploaded file through a couple binaries and sends it back?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Python script that I'd like to share with some colleagues, however they don't have Python installed (or at least not the right version) as well as some additional scientific software.

I was curious if I could use this fairly basic script which gives a file to one binary in my scientific package, massages the data in the script, then provides it to another binary as an opportunity to learn GAE.  Am I mistaken, however, because I couldn't run these binaries on GAE, precluding the whole thing?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question right, you have a bunch of binaries that do some scientific processing, and a python script that takes input, and routes it through the science programs.

If your science binaries are jar files, it may be doable with GAE.  Although you can't run python and Java on the same instance, there are ways to work around it with a python instance and a separate Java instance.

If your binaries are native code, then no, can't be done with GAE.  There's other providers like AWS that give you access to the OS on the VM.  You can probably do it there.